# How do you setup a maven java project that can also make use of groovy?

Tags: java, maven-2, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I'm working on a large existing java project using maven to manage our builds / releases.
I'm interested in using groovy to replace some of our Java classes where we can benefit from it's dynamic nature.

How do I go about doing this using maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [the gmaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects)?

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted it to. I actually looked at it first and from the documentation it looked like it was for building "groovy" projects primarily. It worked great in a mixed environment though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is listed on the [Groovy Wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Compiling+With+Maven2), also have a look at [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home).